# Как реализовать step definition для calabash тестового сценария для CreditCard.apk под Android?

Tags: android, ruby

Всем доброго дня! Написал приложение под Android (прототип указан ниже по ссылке).

Изучил все тулы / мануалы по составлению calabash тестового сценария, также прочитал книгу "The Cucumber book". Не понимаю одного, например хотя бы, **как реализовать step defenitions на ruby, чтобы сделать первоначальный ввод номера кредитной карты.** Допустим, я могу написать в шаге сценария номер карты,

```
Background:
  Given I press "CreditCardEntryDemo"
  And   I press "form_with_zip"

Scenario: Credit card number identity
    When I enter "4242 4242 4242 4242" into field with id "form_with_zip"
    And  I check of the corrrect number of digits for the credit card
    Then the form should be redisplayed with CVV and MM/YY
    And  the form should be activate a button called "Prev"
```

и дальше в step defenition написать регулярное выражение по этому номеру, после чего сделать вызов **query("*")** для просмотра идентификатора объектов в моем **apk**. 
***Вопросы:
1) Как связать идентификатор моего поля CustomView c данными, которые пользователь вводит в номере карты?***
После запуска тестового сценария и получения подсказки, как можно реализовать шаги в сценарии

```
When(/^I enter "([^"]*)" into field with id "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

When(/^I check of the corrrect number of digits for the credit card$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Then(/^the form should be redisplayed with CVV and MM\/YY$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

Then(/^the form should be activate a button called "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

хотелось бы написать реализацию данных подсказок, например как что то в этом роде:

```
#Ввод номера карты в соответствии заданными регулярными выражениями
When(/^I enter "(^4[0-9]{15}?+^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$+^3[47][0-9]{13}$+^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$+)" into field with id "([^"]*)"$/) do |number, idField|
  # TODO something
end

#Проверку правильности набранного номера, думаю, можно опустить из-за
#регулярных выражений предыдущего шага. НО надо еще как то вернуть 
#сами данные в поле CustomView с id form_with_zip.
When(/^I check of the corrrect number of digits for the credit card$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

#После ввода номера карты, должно появиться в этом поле CustomView невидимый 
#CVV и MM/YY
Then(/^the form should be redisplayed with CVV and MM\/YY$/) do
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end

#Должна стать активной кнопка "Prev"
Then(/^the form should be activate a button called "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1|
  pending # Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
end
```

***2) Как сделать абстрактный ввод данных в тесте сценария, если это возможно?***
То есть в тестовом сценарии (см. выше) написан номер карты "4242 4242 4242 4242".
 *Можно ли проверить правильность работы приложения на ввод других каких - то номеров без собственноручного ввода?*

***3) И как вернуть данные номера в поле CustomView, куда в приложении пользователь вводит данные его банковской карты?***
Выше в комментариях подсказок step definitions уже упоминалось про возврат правильно набранного номера банковской карты в поле CustomView с id form_with_zip (описание этого объекта представлено выше). *Так как же это сделать? :)*

***4) Чуть не забыл, как в реализацию step definitions добавить проверку на смену картинок в поле ввода?***
При правильном наборе номера карты, в этом поле ввода должна смениться картинка неопределенной карты на картинку карты, которая соответствует своему регулярному выражению. Например, номер "4242 4242 4242 4242" - это Visa, то есть первая картинка сменится на картинку карты Visa.

*Ссылка на прототип приложения:*
http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1667

Comment: а можете ли пояснить все три вопроса короткими примерами, напр. хотелось бы вот так и сяк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Если всегда один и тот же номер:**

```
When(/^I enter credit card number$/) do 
   touch("* id:'input_id'") #id элемента
   wait_for_keyboard
   keyboard_enter_text('1234') # любой номер (будет захардкожен)
   hide_soft_keyboard
end
```

**Если номер меняется, можно задать переменную:**

```
When(/^I enter credit card number$/) do 
   @code='1234'
   touch("* id:'input_id'") #id элемента
   wait_for_keyboard
   keyboard_enter_text(@code) #переменная code
   hide_soft_keyboard
end
```

**Если хотите прописать в фиче номер:**

В фиче будет выглядеть так:

```
When I enter credit card number '1234'


When(/^I enter credit card number "([^"]*)"$/) do |number|
   touch("* id:'input_id'") #id элемента
   wait_for_keyboard
   keyboard_enter_text(number)
   hide_soft_keyboard
end
```